# What does WCF with the return of the method IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest?

Tags: .net, wcf

What does WCF with the return of the method **`IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest`**?
All I have encountered was **`return null;`** examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It passes the value to the `BeforeSendReply` method, and it can be used to correlate the two calls. You can find one example of a non-null value being returned in the example on the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

WCF does nothing with the return value.

From [IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest.aspx):

> The return value can be any object that you want to use for
>   correlation purposes; it is returned to you as the correlationState
>   parameter in the BeforeSendReply method.

Comment: It doesn't "do nothing" with the value - it passes it to the BeforeSendRequest method.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, I do understand your answer, and both are acceptable. Thank you for the reply